# how to solve this partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

while in its equilibrium position a uniform string stretched between the points (0,0) and (ℓ,0) (hint cn=0 since equilibruim)

[image]

[image]

Comment: $g(x)$ should not be defined in terms of $t$?

Comment: How is that $g$ different from the original $g$, which is incorrect as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you mean the wave equation should be solved here, which it more or less has.  Your job is to match the boundary condition given.  You can start by taking the time derivative of your given solution:

$$\dot{y}(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \pi a}{\ell} \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{\ell} \right)} \left [-C_n \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi a t}{\ell} \right)} + D_n \cos{\left ( \frac{n \pi a t}{\ell} \right)}\right ] $$

This means that

$$\dot{y}(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \pi a}{\ell} D_n \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{\ell} \right)} = g(x)$$

This is a Fourier series, so you find the coefficients as follows:

$$\frac{n \pi a}{\ell} D_n = \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^{\ell} dx \, g(x) \, \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{\ell} \right)}}{\displaystyle \int_0^{\ell} dx \, \sin^2{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{\ell} \right)}}$$

Now, I suspect your definition of $g$ is not right because the dimensions don't line up; I will take

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{a x}{\ell} & 0 \le x \le \frac{\ell}{2} \\ a \left ( 1-\frac{x}{\ell}\right) & \frac{\ell}{2} \lt x \le \ell \end{cases} $$

I will let you handle the details of the integration; I get

$$D_n = 2 \ell \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

This leaves $C_n$; this should clearly be zero for all $n$ because the string is initially in the equilibrium position.  Thus the solution is

$$y(x,t) = 2 \ell \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{\ell} \right)} \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi a t}{\ell} \right)} $$

Comment: but look at the function of g(x) in your solution  is not equal to my function ''sub 1 by L '' in the second function

Comment: could anybody  help me just find Dn ?